# Update Multiple Git Repositories - Improved Output

Tags: git, config, alias

I found this command online that allows me to be in a parent directory and it will go through each directory and update the git repository in each one.  I can also do this to get the status etc.  I was wondering if there was a way to clean up the output and have it be more user-readable.

```
ls | xargs -I{} git -C {} pull
```

This works well but just gives me the response.  I would like it to show the name of the repository and then the response, etc.  Is there a way to force it to do this easily?  Hopefully using an alias in some way?

Comment: Google has a tool named *Repo*, which can manipulate multiple git repos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
for dir in * ; do if [ \! -L ${dir} -a -d ${dir}/.git ] ; then (cd ${dir} ; echo ":::: ${dir} ::::"; git pull) ; fi ; done
```

It goes through every item in your current directory, and if the item is the top of a git repository, it will print the directory name and perform a `git pull`. You can add any other commands you want to perform in each repository after the `git pull`.

EDIT:

you can alias it by adding it to `~./bash_aliases` as a shell function:

```
git-pull-all () {
  #command here
}
```

Or, if for some reason you wanted to add it as a git alias instead of a bash alias, you can prepend the command name with `!` when you create it:

```
git config --global alias.pull-all '!COMMAND_HERE'
```

Comment: Yes that works, but I was hoping to be able to alias it in some way, so I could run something like "git pull-all" at the parent level.  Since "find" isn't a git command, the alias will not work, from what I understand.

Comment: Thank you so much, the alias solution worked perfectly.